# nexenta and the free access to web interface

Tags: configuration, nexenta

In nexentastor default intallation any users that knows the ip can connect to it and access in read-only mode to the web interface
In my opinion this can rappresent a problem because anyone can read details of my infrastructure: shares, luns, version of OS, activity..

It's possible authenticate the user before show any information?
what do you think about? i'm paranoic?

(Changing the tcp port is a bad solution for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings --> Preferences --> Read_access_required = yes